# Extract ProductQuantizer from FAISS IndexIVF

Tags: faiss

I'm trying to extract the pre-precessing part (OPQ) of my FAISS Index so that I can return the approximate vectors as part of my API response.

Specifically, I am not able to extract the Product Quantizer from the Index.

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import faiss

d = 1024
index_name = 'OPQ64_1280,IVF512_HNSW32,PQ64x8'
index = faiss.index_factory(d, index_name, faiss.METRIC_INNER_PRODUCT)
embeddings = np.random.normal(size=(1000,d)).astype(np.float32)
index.train(embeddings)


# Now, I want to apply just the OPQ encoder to my query:
query = np.random.normal(size=(1,d)).astype(np.float32)
quantizer = index.quantizer # This is still a IndexIVF class (!)

# ERROR HERE
encoded_vec = quantizer.compute_code(query) ## This doesn't work


# And compare against another encoded vector I can fetch from the index
index = faiss.extract_index_ivf(index)
index.set_direct_map_type(faiss.DirectMap.Array)
index.reconstruct(1).shape # returns the encoded vector at position = 1 (d=1080)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out ! One needs to apply the OPQ before the encode / decode step.

Here is the code snippet:

```py
# Extract the OPQ matrix
mat = faiss.downcast_VectorTransform(index.chain.at(0))

# Apply it to the query
rot_query = mat.apply(query)

# Now, apply PQ
ind2 = faiss.extract_index_ivf(index)
encoded_query2 = ind2.sa_decode(ind2.sa_encode(rot_query))

# You can check whether the encoding is correct by adding to the index and checking how it's represented with `reconstruct`
index.add(query)
index2 = faiss.extract_index_ivf(index)
index2.set_direct_map_type(faiss.DirectMap.Array) # Is this necessary? Not sure
encoded_query = index2.reconstruct(index.ntotal-1)

assert np.allclose(encoded_query2, encoded_query)
```

Longer [discussion](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/issues/2994)